# Multiline sed regex extraction issue: part of buffer matches

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have to extract data from a log, and I'm trying to use sed to extract the data from 3 lines. The log entries (after grepping) look like this:

```
Tuesday March 11 2014
INBOUND>>>>>  06:22:10:066 Eventid:141004(3)
[SGW-S11/S4]GTPv2C Rx PDU, from 172.9.9.1:10000 to 173.10.10.1:2123 (187)
TEID: 0x00000000, Message type: EGTP_CREATE_SESSION_REQUEST (0x20)
```

I need to extract the "from IP", the "to IP", and the "Message Type".
This is what I have as of now:

```
sed -n '1!N; s/^INBOUND>>>>>.*\n.*from \([0-9.]*\).* to \([0-9.]*\).*/\1 \2/p'
```

- When I extend it to the third line, to extract the message type, with:

  `sed -n '1!N; s/^INBOUND>>>>>.*\n.*from \([0-9.]*\).* to \([0-9.]*\).*\n.*, Message type: \([A-Z_]*\).*/\1 \2/p'`

  The entire pattern doesn't match.
- This doesn't match the string unless there is a line before the `INBOUND>>>>>` string, which I think should match, since the `^` indicates the start of line. (This isn't really a problem since there is a datestamp, just a curiosity)

Bash Version: GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Sed Version: GNU sed version 4.1.5

Could you please give me any pointers on this? Thanks in advance.

P.S. The IPs can be IPv4 or IPv6, but I will change the IP regex once this problem's solved.

P.P.S. I need to use a regex i.e. not awk, because there will be other patterns too; this is the first, and I'm having problems :(

Answer (score 1):

- Your entire pattern

  `sed -n '1!N; s/^INBOUND>>>>>.*\n.*from \([0-9.]*\).* to \([0-9.]*\).*\n.*, Message type:\([A-Z_]*\).*/\1 \2/p'`

  can't match because *you're missing a space* between `Message type:` and `\([A-Z_]*\)`
- Are you sure there are no hidden characters before `INBOUND` (when you omit the first line)?

This one works for me:

```
sed -r 's/.*from ([0-9.:]*) to ([0-9.:]*).*Message type: ([A-Z_]*).*/\1 \2 \3/'
```

[image]
(note that I used the `-r` flag so I won't have to escape the brackets)

Comment: Hey, that missing space was a typo. I've corrected it above in the question. It still doesn't work. I tried your solution, but it doesn't work. I've also added the bash+sed versions to the question, maybe it's an older version?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` and no regex:

```
awk -F" |:" '/^INBOUND/ {getline;print $5 RS $8;getline;print $7}' file
172.9.9.1
173.10.10.1
EGTP_CREATE_SESSION_REQUEST
```

You say this is date out from a `grep`, it may be incorporated to the `awk`
Give us all data and how you like to output to be, and we will help you.

```
awk -F" |:" '/^INBOUND/ {getline;printf "%s %s",$5,$8;getline;print "",$7}' file
172.9.9.1 173.10.10.1 EGTP_CREATE_SESSION_REQUEST
```

Comment: Sorry, but I need regexes as the user will provide a regex for multiple log entries.

Comment: Normal a field have a name in front like `Message type: EGTP_CREATE_SESSION_REQUES`, then `Message type` can be used to get data, so regex may not be needed.